# Parsing issues with Windows Phone7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing

I'm working on an application with Windows Phone 7, which displays data from a specific URI, but it won't work. I'm stack,help me please. This is my XML :

```
<rss version="2.0">
   <channel>
      <title>info</title>
      <link>http://www.info.net</link>
      <description>Trouvez toutes les actualités en direct sur info.net ...</description>
      <language>fr</language>
      <copyright></copyright>
      <pubDate></pubDate>
      <image>
            <url></url>
            <title></title>
            <link>http://www.info.net</link>
            <width>200</width>
            <height>200</height>
          </image>
    <item>
<title>Actualités » Info News » News Régionales : Main info</title>
    <link>http://www.info.net/fr/actualite/actualites_info-news_news-regionales/my-main-info/54</link>
    <pubDate>Thu, 29 Dec 2011 00:22:00 +0100</pubDate>
    <description><![CDATA[<img align='left' width='139' src='http://www.info.net/uploads/content/thumbnails/2011122902313__news.jpg'> My main info details : ...]]></description> 
</item><item>
    .
    .
    .
      </item></channel></rss>
```

And i want to display a list that contains:

```
Main info (title)
http://www.info.net/uploads/content/thumbnails/2011122902313__news.jpg (description)
My main info details (description)
```

This is my C# code:

```
  var doc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(e.Result));
            var items = from c in doc.Descendants("item")
                    select new RSSitem()
                    {
                        Title = c.Element("title").Value,
                        Photo = c.Element("img").Attribute("src").Value,
                        Description = c.Element("description").Value,
                        Link = c.Element("link").Value,
                    };
            ListBoxNews.ItemsSource = items;
```

Comment: what doesn'T work ? doesn't it compile ? doesn't it display anything ? does it display something wrong/incomplete/too much ?

Comment: It only displays the title :(

Comment: Side note, I'd recommend adding a `ToList` to the end of your LINQ query; otherwise the query would be re-evaluated if the ListBox refreshed its items.

Comment: You're asking me to change my listing method?

Answer (score 0):

The `<img>` tag is not part of your XML document, but an *HTML* element in a CDATA node of the description element.

To extract it, you'll need to use the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) (`HtmlAgilityPack` on [NuGet](http://nuget.org/)).

Here's an updated version of your code:

*(I converted your LINQ expression to use the extension methods as sequential code doesn't work well in LINQ expressions)*

```
var items = doc.Descendants("item")
               .Select(c =>
               {
                    string descriptionHtml = c.Element("description").Value;
                    HtmlDocument descriptionDoc = new HtmlDocument();

                    descriptionDoc.LoadHtml(descriptionHtml);

                    HtmlNode imageNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//img[@src]");

                    string imageUrl = (imageNode != null)
                        ? imageNode.GetAttributeValue("src", null)
                        : null;

                    // This might need further looking at, depending on your HTML
                    string description = doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;

                    return new RSSitem() 
                    { 
                        Title = c.Element("title").Value, 
                        Photo = imageUrl, 
                        Description = description, 
                        Link = c.Element("link").Value, 
                    };

               }).ToList();
```

Comment: I did download the Html Agility Pack, but i couldn't add it as a new Reference.

Comment: @MarTech - You need the WP build, which for some reason is only available via [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org). You should be to install NuGet on the Express version of VS, then you add a "package reference" (by right clicking on references) and find `HtmlAgilityPack`.

Comment: Am i supposed to find the HtmlAgilityPack in Windows SDKs when i have to add it as a Reference?

Comment: No, NuGet is a package manager that allows you to add references to things that will be downloaded from the internet. When you right click on references you should see a "Manage NuGet Packages..." option. If not, go to [nuget.org](http://nuget.org) and download/install NuGet (it's an official Microsoft product).

Answer (score -1):

for c data node something like

```
XmlNode cDataNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("channel/description").ChildNodes[0];
```

string finalData = cDataNode.InnerText.Trim();

Comment: Could you be more explicit please

Comment: you only get title because way you are extracting Photo and Description propery is incorrent, there is no attribute src in description node and for Description property something like code code above can be used to get CDATA

Comment: What he is saying is that the content in the description element is text that looks like XML.  You can't do an xpath query into CDATA.