# Limit number of characters on TextBlock

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, textblock

How can we limit the number of characters that we want to display on our TextBlock with Windows Phone 7?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you limit the length of Text visible in a WPF TextBlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7170817/can-you-limit-the-length-of-text-visible-in-a-wpf-textblock)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

1. You could set the `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight` properties of your TextBlock. Any remaining text would get truncated.
2. Substring the text before assigning it to the TextBlock. For example:

```cs
    var str = "SomeReallyLongString";
    var maxLength = 10;
    yourTextBlock.Text = str.Length > maxLength ? str.Substring(0, maxLength) : str;
```

Comment: It works, thanks.But still have a problem; it displays the last  characters("LongString") and i want the inverse (SomeReally") ?!

Comment: Can you please help me out with my parsing problem? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666983/parsing-issues-with-windows-phone7/8667178#8667178)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a read-only textbox instead and set its `MaxLength` property. Alternatively you could also handle the `TextInput` event and truncate the text if it's longer than the max length.

Answer (score 1):

Use a converter if you are binding a value to your textblock. You can assign a value (parameter) to the converter to set the max number of characters. This will work beter then maxheight and maxwidth because it wont bother about the font size.